# Android Button positioning on different screens

Tags: android

Hi i have a problem when i add a button in my relative layout the position doesn't effect on different screen and android adjust the size of button when run app on big screen but the problem is that when i add a background image to button it doesn't set the size of the button for big screen it shows the button as if i am on a small screen

```
<RelativeLayout       
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"

 >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="40px"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bt" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its because you fixed the `layout_height` and `layout_width` with `px`. Try using `dp` on that and give feedback of what you find.

Comment: Don't use `px` for sizes - always use `dp`. Also, if you want a custom background image, use nine-patch bitmaps. See http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: changing it to dp helped but what i want is that i have adjusted size of button for normal screen so it looks good on normal screen but when see on large screen it looks small so what i want is when i see it on large screen button size should with respect to large screen